# Generating binary numbers with constraints

Tags: python, binary

Help me generate a script in python or another language that returns every 32 bit binary number meeting the following constraint:  considering the patterns of 1’s and 0’s inherent in each binary number, there may be a maximum of one case per binary number where the pattern of zeroes does not repeat at least once.  So if we were doing the exercise on smaller 7 bit binary, 1010011 is not valid (0, and 00 are unique), but 1010100 is valid (0 is found twice, 00 once) and 1010101 is valid (0 is found 3 times).  Finally, these numbers should be thought of as rings, such that trailing zeroes and zeroes at the beginning are considered one group (eg 0010 contains the set 000).

I am struggling with this because my normal approach would be to use brute force… generate a list of all binaries and then subject each number to the constraint.  However there are 4.3 billion 32 bit combinations, making my usual approach too slow.

Comment: You are still going to end up with a very large list of numbers which match your constraints. Are you storing each of those numbers or just counting them?

Comment: Storing, ideally.  I want to be able to search by bit positions later ( for example, all matches were 1 is in the 13th position) so I was planning to make it in to a table

Comment: So, consider the bit pattern `10101`. This has exactly two `0`s which matches your constraint. If you then append another 27 bits you will get a 32 bit number. So there you immediately have over 134 million numbers to store. You could start with those numbers. See how long it takes to store those numbers, make them into a table and search them in various ways.

Comment: Hmm so what approach would you take?  Write a generator that creates the numbers on the fly as needed, rather than store in a table and filter?

Comment: As I said, you could start by storing the numbers I suggested and see how you get on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a fast enough solution for 32 bits but I have something that's a bit better than brute force:

The approach breaks down the problem in layers that allow early exclusion of  patterns that won't produce a valid set of bits.

A group of consecutive zeros is delimited by 1s on each side.  And, since the binary number is treated as a "ring", we can view each group as a "1" followed by a number of consecutive zeros (including no zeros at all).

This means that the 32 bits will be divided in groups with a total length of 32.  Thus, the starting point can be the [partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of 32 into parts (groups) that add up to 32.

Of these partitions, we would excludes the ones that have more than one occurrence of a non-repeated group size (other than a size of one which is a "1" not followed by any "0").  This allows us to exclude group patterns before any permutation or rotation is performed.

Once we obtain the combinations of partition sizes, we still need to find the distinct permutations of these group sizes to convert them into bit patterns.

Finally, because we defined the groups as starting with "1", we are missing the bit patterns where a sequence of zeros wraps around the boundaries of the 32 bits. This will require performing a few rotations get a complete result.

Here is a function to generate partitions of a given size for a number N:

```
def partition(N,size):
    if size == 1 :
        yield (N,)                           # base case, only 1 part
        return
    for a in range(N//size+1):               # smaller part followed by
        for p in partition(N-a*size,size-1): # equal or larger ones
            yield (a, *(n+a for n in p))     # recursing on delta only
```

We use the partitions in a generator that will produce valid group combinations by filtering out the partitions that have more than one non-repeating group size (except zero-size groups).  The partition() function produces entries in the range 0...N which corresponds to the number of 0s in each group.  This is why it is given size-count as the total value in order to exclude the number of 1s from the computation.

```
from collections import Counter
def genGroups(size=32):
    for count in range(1,size):
        for group in partition(size-count,count):
            partCounts = Counter(group)
            if sum(n and c==1 for n,c in partCounts.items())>1:
                continue
            yield group
```

Once we get the valid group combinations, we still need to find the distinct permutations of these group sizes:

```
def permuteDistinct(A):
    if len(A) == 1:
        yield tuple(A) # single value
        return
    used = set()               # track starting value
    for i,n in enumerate(A):   # for each starting value
        if n in used: continue # not yet used
        used.add(n)
        for p in permuteDistinct(A[:i]+A[i+1:]): 
            yield (n,*p)       # starting value & rest
```

The genBits() function combines these generators to obtain the groups and convert them into bit patterns.  It then rotates them to get the variants that wrap around the binary bit list.

```
def genBits(size=32):
    yield "0"*size                          # edge case
    seen = set()
    for grouping in genGroups(size):              # 
        for order in permuteDistinct(grouping):
            bits = "".join("1"+"0"*n for n in order)
            yield bits
            i = bits.index("0")
            bits = bits[i:]+bits[:i]
            if bits in seen: continue
            seen.add(bits)
            while bits.startswith("0"):
                yield bits
                bits = bits[1:]+bits[:1]
    yield "1"*size                          # edge case
```

output:

```
for bits in genBits(5):
    print(bits)

00000
10000
00001
00010
00100
01000
11000
00011
00110
01100
10001
11100
00111
01110
11001
10011
11010
01011
10110
01101
10101
11110
01111
11101
11011
10111
11111
```

performance:

```
from time import time
start = time()
count = sum(1 for _ in genBits(24))  # 8,949,112  bit patterns
print(count, time()-start)           # 35 seconds 

# other sizes / times

genBits(22)  #  2,213,116  in 10  seconds
genBits(25)  # 17,938,807  in 77  seconds 
genBits(27)  # 71,767,133  in 323 seconds
genBits(29)  # 286,383,035 in 21  minutes
genBits(32)  # should give 2 billion patterns in roughly 3 hours
```

The time (and number of solutions) grows exponentially.  I wasn't patient enough to wait for the 32 bit result.

In order to check the result, i wrote a bit pattern validation function that I used in a brute force solution:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

def isvalid(bits):
    p = bits.find("1")
    if p<0: return True         # all zeros
    bits = bits[p:]+bits[:p]    # rotate to start on a 1
    counts = Counter(len(g) for bit,(*g,) in groupby(bits) if bit=="0")
    return sum(c==1 for c in counts.values()) < 2


N = 20
sum(isvalid(f"{n:0{N}b}") for n in range(1<<N)) # 543,876 : 9 secs
sum(1 for _ in genBits(N))                      # 543,876 : 2 secs
```